# 'Mountain' does not implement interface member 'IBiome.height'

Tags: c#

New to interfaces, please tell me what I am doing wrong here:

```
public interface IBiome
{
    private float[] height { get; }
    private int[] tiles { get; }
}
public class Mountain : IBiome
{
    public float[] height = { 1f };
    public int[] tiles = { Tile.Stone };
}
```

I get error: `'Mountain' does not implement interface member 'IBiome.height'`. Same for tiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `Get` to your implementation. Right now they're fields when they should be properties. That will match your interface. Right now you're mismatched.

```
public class Mountain : IBiome
{
    public float[] height { get; } = { 1f };
    public int[] tiles { get; } = { Tile.Stone };
}
```

With expanded getters instead of auto properties, these properties have a full backing store and use that for initialization.

```
public class Mountain : IBiome
{
    private float[] _height = { 1f };
    public float[] height 
    { 
        get { return _height; }
    }

    private int[] _tiles = { Tile.Stone };
    public int[] tiles
    {
        get { return _tiles; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, now I get "Feature 'readonly automatically implemented properties' is not available in C# 4."

Comment: Ah then it may be best to use fields, remove `{ get; }` from both the implementation and the interface. Or upgrade from C#4

Comment: "Interfaces cannot contain fields". Damn, it just doesn't let me do it.

Comment: Yeah forgot that one second